# set XmlDataProvider source without saving file

Tags: c#, binding, xmldataprovider

in my browser wpf application i use databinding to xml that comes from my database.
to bind it the better way i use the XmlDataProvider.

in the beginning i declare

```
<Grid.DataContext>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Name="listdataxml" XPath="EssenceList/Essence" Source="model.xml"/>
</Grid.DataContext>
```

but later i need to point it to a new XDocument. The question: is there a way to set my XmlDataProvider to an XDocument, without saving it somewhere and using URI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the XDocument to an XmlDocument in memory and then set the Document property on listdataxml.  See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508572/converting-xdocument-to-xmldocument-and-vice-versa) for how to convert from an XDocument to an XmlDocument.

Put together, it will look like this:

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
using (var xmlReader = xDocument.CreateReader())
{
    xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
}
listdataxml.Document = xmlDocument;
```