# Converting XmlElement To XElement and vice-versa in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting XDocument to XmlDocument and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508572/converting-xdocument-to-xmldocument-and-vice-versa)

Is there a simple way to convert XmlElement To XElement?