# XDocument to JSON, JsonProperties

Tags: c#, json, properties, json.net, linq-to-xml

I am working with C# (ASP.Net, MVC) and Newtonsoft for JSON serialization. I get an XDocument like the one below which I would like to have in JSON format, for the view.

```
<group>
  <name>Group 1</name>
  <description><p>Description</p></description>
  <section>
    ..
  </section>
  <section>
    ..
  </section>
</group>
```

I have an Extension like this

```
private static readonly JsonSerializer jSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings {});

public static string ToJson(this object obj) {
  using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()) {
    jSerializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
    return writer.ToString();
  }
}
```

The problem now is, that the description gets deserialized, so I have something like

```
... "description": { "p": "Description Text" }
```

which will be displayed as "[Object object]" when just posted as is.

- Is there a way to set some JsonProperties for the XDocument (in general), without generating a completely deserialized class?
- If not, is there a way to set some JsonProperty saying "Keep this as string, do not serialize any further"
- If I were to use an XSD generated class for this, what "type" would I need to set? "anyType"?

Help would be appreciated,
Best regards.

Answer (score 13):

I am adding this answer due to it's google search rank when looking up "c# convert xml to json XDocument".

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xDocument);
```

This answer uses the more modern `XNode` vs `XmlNode`

Comment: I originally down voted until I realized this answer has `SerializeXNode` and other answer is `SerializeXmlNode` and is not the same answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, may fortune shine upon you!  :)

Answer (score 4):

Using Json.NET you can serialize an XML node directly to JSON using the following line:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlNode);
```

To convert your `XDocument` to `XmlDocument` see this question:

[Converting XDocument to XmlDocument and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508572/converting-xdocument-to-xmldocument-and-vice-versa)

You can then use your converted `XmlDocument` as parameter for `SerializeXmlNode()` because it inherits from `XmlNode`.

Comment: I would like to not use the JsonConvert, because it does not use the same serializer settings. It's not really an issue, I know how to convert Json to XmlDocument. But you are basically answering my question in going over XML to object and not directly. Last thing I would need to know is which type I'd have to set in the XSD file.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but why are you not using `SerializeXNode` instead of `SerializeXmlNode`

Comment: @JPHellemons I have no clue. Maybe the method hasn't existed yet when I wrote the answer. But I honestly don't know anymore.