# Obtaining XmlElement from XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have to pass a whole XML document into a 3rd party function. The parameter is `XmlElement`.

To do this until now, I've successfully been using this:

```
XmlDocument doc;
//doc = ...
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
3rdPartyFunction(root);
```

But now I'm using `XDocument` instead of `XmlDocument`:

```
XDocument doc;
//doc = ...
//how to call 3rdPartyFunction?
```

How do I call the function in this case? Can I convert from "Xml" to "X"?

Comment: Why don't you just read it in as an `XmlElement` in the first place?

Comment: @JeffMercado I don't control the 3rd party function and can't change it.

Comment: @roger.james Deleted my post since the suggestion became irrelevant.In this case you [would look @ this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508572/converting-xdocument-to-xmldocument-and-vice-versa) for transformation.

Comment: You misunderstood my question, but my question misunderstood your question. :) I missed the first part of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
var newDoc = new XmlDocument();
newDoc.LoadXml(doc.ToString());
3rdPartyFunction(newDoc);
```

Comment: What happens if the xml file has 250K lines? :)

Comment: You are right, it's better to use doc.CreateReader() and newDoc.Load()

Comment: The parameter type is `XmlElement`; you cannot just pass `XmlDocument`.

Answer (score 2):

[Updated]

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
using (XmlReader reader = xdoc.CreateReader())
{
    xmldoc.Load(reader);
}
XmlElement root = xmldoc.DocumentElement;
3rdPartyFunction(root);
```