# Update existing code from XMLDocument to XDocument

Tags: linq-to-xml, system.xml

Good morning guys,

I am working on a project where I need to take some code OK a lot of code using the xmldocument classes and make it compatible with silverlight which only supports xdocument (system.xml to system.xml.linq)

The question is, has anyone found a quick or automated way to do this? I know there are several differences between the two and how they work but it seems like it should be possible. Unfortunately I don't have time to write something to do this for me.

Comment: I don't think there is some existing tool for converting XmlDocument code to LINQ

Comment: I think you are right :) just thought i'd see if anyone here knew of one. Guess not.

Comment: [I found an answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1509094/2079688)