# Read .xml File into XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8.1, live-tile

I have a live tile template such as:

```
<tile>
  <visual version="2">
    <binding template="TileSquare150x150Text02" fallback="TileSquareText02">
      <text id="1">Text Field 1 (larger text)</text>
      <text id="2">Text Field 2</text>
    </binding>  
  </visual>
</tile>
```

I can read it into an `XmlDocument` like so:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><tile>");
            sb.Append("<visual version=\"2\"><binding template=\"TileSquare150x150Text04\" fallback=\"TileSquareText04\"><text id=\"1\">Text Field 1</text></binding></visual></tile>");
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.LoadXml(sb.ToString());
```

But I would really like to read it directly from a file, as this will quickly become extremely messy.

`XmlDocument.Load` is not supported for Windows Phone 8.1, so I cannot just pump in the filename.  `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);` is also unacceptable to Windows Phone 8.1.  `XDocument` did not seem to have a friendly method.

What can I do to read the .xml file to a `string` so I can plug it into XmlDocument for a Windows Phone 8.1 app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XDocument.Load can load from the file. It is supported in Windows Phone 8.1, according to MSDN:

- [XDocument.Load Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Supported in: Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone 8, Silverlight 8.1

XDocument.Parse loads from a string, containing XML.

Regarding conversion from XDocument to XmlDocument, you can use [@Muhammad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24976440/897326). If you decide to implement it, consider a potential performance issue with large XML files (read my comment underneath it).

Comment: Well I'll be! I was initializing the XDocument then trying to load the instantiation.  Thanks!  XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("filename");

Comment: unforunately I just found out that I need an XmlDocument. wonder if there is a way to convert...

Comment: @Evorlor: Why do you need to be using XmlDocument? XDocument is very user-friendly, it usually has less lines of code. Converting should be easy, if it's not a lot of code.

Comment: TileNotification requires an XmlDocument in its constructor, not an XDocument. But I can convert it to a string and then make an XmlDocument from there.  Success!  ugly success....but success!  Thanks :)

Comment: @Evorlor: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508572/converting-xdocument-to-xmldocument-and-vice-versa

Comment: i have read it already. thats a lot of unnecessary code.  see muhammed's answer above

Comment: @Evorlor: It may not be as efficient, check another answer from the same thread (and comments underneath): http://stackoverflow.com/a/9376479/897326 More code is not always bad.

Comment: I read that as well, and even tried it. Won't work with Windows Phone 8.1. but i know what you mean. this operation will only be run once when the app closes though, so im not too concerned about inefficiency.

Comment: I don't know where to put the checkmark. Muhammad's answer is the full answer, but your answer is what led there!

Comment: @Evorlor: Flip a coin? :)

Comment: perhaps you could link to his answer in yours? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it in xml document.

```
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.LoadXml(XDocument.Load("Assets/test.xml").ToString());
```

Comment: While this may look like a nice solution, the following thread suggests it may have performance issues due to string conversion (back and forth). It should, however, work well for small XML files, if that's what you are after. For more information, check a comment under this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9376479/897326

Comment: Neolisk is right.  But anyone who is using this for live tiles, you shouldn't be running this code more than once per session anyways.