# How can i get value of attribute base on matched value?

Tags: c#, xml

i want get value of attribute base on matched value. Here my XML file

```
<Setup>
  <Include Type="Product">
    <Value uomid="8078">468922</Value>
    <Value uomid="8078">468908</Value>
  </Include>
</Setup>
```

So, i would like to take uomid base in matched value. And the process in codebehind Ex: I set my parameter value is: 468922 so my result i wanna get is 8078 of 468922 not 8087 of 468908. Thanks

Comment: [*What have you tried?*](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Both the attribute value is same. Is that a typo error?

Comment: Now, I can get parameter value, but i don't know the method to get the element value base on parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below Code:

SearchValue is the value which you wanna search. In your case its "468922"

```
 public string ReturnAttribute(string SearchValue)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Tmp\test.xml");
            string ReturnValue = String.Empty;
            foreach (var item in xdoc.Descendants("Value"))
            {
                if (item.Value == SearchValue)
                {
                    ReturnValue=item.FirstAttribute.Value;

                }
            }
            return ReturnValue;
        }
```

Comment: That is the same way when i using XmlDocument??

Comment: Convert XMLDocument to XDocument first and then try the method.

Comment: Convertion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508572/converting-xdocument-to-xmldocument-and-vice-versa